# In Angular 1.x, including a directive in a component?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive for forcing uppercase in input fields which I would like to reuse in multiple components, but I have an error when I try to include in my component.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20string

my_page.html

```
....

   <script src="components.js"></script>
   <script src="my_compnenet.js"></script>
....
```

components.js

```
(function (angular)
{

   'use strict';
   angular.module('components', [])
   .directive('uppercased', function () {
      return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (input) {
               return input ? input.toUpperCase() : "";
            });
            element.css("text-transform", "uppercase");
         }
      };
   });
})(window.angular);
```

my_componenet.js

```
angular.
  module('app').
  component('my_component', {
    templateUrl: 'my_page.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', 'components'],
    bindings: {
      name: '='
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: controller should be a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to inject the directive module to the component module

```
angular.
  module('app',['components']).
  component('my_component', {
    templateUrl: 'my_page.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$timeout'],
    bindings: {
      name: '='
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: this gives me a different error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=translateFilterProvider%20%3C-%20translateFilter

Comment: are you using `angular-translate` if so please post the full code

Comment: I'm not using `angular-translate` in this component, the only code I excluded are a few additional bindings. when I don't include `['components']` I don't get the injector error, but I do get the error in my original post